# Eclipse PDT Zend Debugger not working with Mac OSX Lion

Tags: php, macos, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

I am using Eclipse with below configuration on Mac

```
Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736
...
PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature 3.0.0.v20110516-1100
...
Zend Debugger Feature   5.3.18.v20110322
```

It was working perfectly fine till I had Mac Snow Leopard but as soon as I upgraded to Mac Lion, Eclipse has stopped encountering any breakpoints and PHP web page execution goes till end and terminates.

Nothing has changed after that I tried to update the eclipse/pdt/zend debugger but did not find any updates.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to get the debugger to work on Eclipse in OSX Lion.

Eventually gave up and tried another IDE, Netbeans.

Hope you find a solution